# C for 16f628, Program Counter goes haywire

Tags: c, pic

I have a new problem here. 
I'm still learning C for PIC (xc8 compiler) and as a beginner project i'm doing a thermometer with the popular ds18b20 and a pic16f628 i had lying around. 
My program does behave good when it is allowed to run but while i was playing with pointers, structures, arrays etc. to return more than one value in a function i noticed something went haywire and now the PC goes back and forth not allowing the program to run sequentially, at least that's what i see if I use the simulator in mplabx. I'm quite sure I have forgot something about program and/or memory locations but i can't figure out what or why. Can someone help me? I paste here the main code, what else do you need?

```
/*
 * File:   termometro.c
 * Author: zakkos 
 * Created on April 18, 2013, 2:20 PM
 *
 * /
/*ESSENTIAL DEFINITIONS*/
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
/*INCLUSIONS*/
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lcd.h>
#include <1-wire.h>
/*CONFIG PRAGMA*/
#pragma config BOREN = OFF, CPD = OFF, FOSC = INTOSCIO, MCLRE = OFF, WDTE = OFF, CP = OFF, LVP = OFF, PWRTE = ON

//typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

void read_temp(void);

union {
    char eratura;
    char decimali;
}temps;

int main(void) {

    INTCON = 0x00;
    PIE1 = 0x00;

    CMCON = 0x07; //disabilito i comparatori - disable comparators

    TRISA = 0x00;
    PORTA = 0x00;

    TRISB = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    const char decims[16] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9};
    char temp;

    lcd_init();
    lcd_send_cmd(LCD_CLR);
    lcd_send_cmd(LCD_HOME);
    writeString("Hello,");
    lcd_send_cmd(LCD_LN2);
    writeString("World!");
    __delay_ms(1000);
    while(1)
    {
        read_temp();
        lcd_send_cmd(LCD_CLR);
        lcd_send_cmd(LCD_HOME);
        writeString("Temp:");
        lcd_send_cmd(LCD_LN2);
        if((temps.eratura & 0x80)){                             //if sign bit is set
                temps.eratura = ~temps.eratura;                 //2's complement
                temps.eratura += 1;                             
                temps.decimali = ~temps.decimali;               //2's complement
                temps.decimali += 1;
                lcd_send_dat(0x2D);                             //minus
        }
        temp = (temps.eratura/100)& 0x0F;                       //centinaia 157/100=1 (hundreds)
        if(temp){
            lcd_send_dat(0x30 | temp);
            temp = ((temps.eratura/10)%10) & 0x0F;              //decine    157/10=15%10=5 (tens if hundreds is set, meaning it will display also a 0)
            lcd_send_dat(0x30 | temp);
        } else {
            temp = ((temps.eratura/10)%10) & 0x0F;              //decine    157/10=15%10=5 (tens if hundreds is no set, meaning it will not display if 0)
            if(temp){lcd_send_dat(0x30 | temp);
            }
        }
        lcd_send_dat(0x30 | (temps.eratura%10)& 0x0F);          //unita     157%10=7 (ones)
        lcd_send_dat(0x2E);                                     //dot
        lcd_send_dat(0x30 | decims[temps.decimali] & 0x0F);     //decimals
        lcd_send_dat(0xDF);                                     //degrees
 }
}

void read_temp(void){
    char scratchpad[9];
    while(ow_reset());
    ow_write_byte(0xCC);
    ow_write_byte(0x44);
    while(ow_read_bit()==0);
    __delay_ms(1);
    while(ow_reset());
    ow_write_byte(0xCC);
    ow_write_byte(0xBE);
    for(char k=0;k<10;k++){
        scratchpad[k] = ow_read_byte();
    }
    temps.decimali = scratchpad[0] & 0x0F;
    temps.eratura = (scratchpad[1] << 4)|(scratchpad[0] >> 4);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if stackoverflow is the best place for you to post. You might have more chance here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also try http://www.microchip.com/forums/  although there are some promising answers here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask there too

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the microchip forum they spotted a flaw in the code. Turns out the problem was me, I didn't account for a negative index in the `decims[];` array when it was evaluated in the case of a negative temperature

```
if(temps.eratura < 0){ 
 temps.eratura = -temps.eratura; 
 temps.decimali = -temps.decimali; 
 lcd_send_dat('-'); 
 }
```

then used in

```
lcd_send_dat(decims[temps.decimali]); //decimals
```

the 2's complement of a byte containing only the lower nibble (0x0F) has the most significant nibble set (0xF1). This was the source of all my problems!
Adding a mask on the lower nibble after complementing the byte solved the problem:

```
if(temps.eratura < 0){ 
 temps.eratura = -temps.eratura; 
 temps.decimali = -temps.decimali & 0x0F; 
 lcd_send_dat('-'); 
 }
```

Thank you all for the answers, you really helped me a lot in understanding how things work!

Answer (score 7):

```
for(char k=0;k<10;k++){
    scratchpad[k] = ow_read_byte();
}
```

...will run from 0-9 (10 characters) while...

```
char scratchpad[9];
```

...only reserves space for 9. This may overwrite the stack (ie the return address)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't noticed that, i'll correct it immediately. But unfortunately the program worked well before I tried using "struct" (and then "union" to see if it changed things) to pass values from read_temp(); to main();
I don't even know if i did it right and if it's the best way to do it, it's only to learn how things work!

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
        temps.eratura = ~temps.eratura;                 //2's complement
        temps.eratura += 1;                             
        temps.decimali = ~temps.decimali;               //2's complement
        temps.decimali += 1;
```

is a big nop as temps is a `union` and not a `struct`.  What are you trying to do here?  Why not:

`temps.eratura = -temps.eratura;`

Perhaps you meant for the second member of the `union` to be an `int`?  In that case, it still fails, but makes a bit more sense in its use in `read_temp`

And you are accessing 10 chars for a 9 char array as others have mentioned.

More Info based on comments:

You definately want to use a struct for your temps as you want 2 distict values in memory.  Also, while I'm not sure what your compiler allows,

```
    if(temps.eratura < 0){              
            temps.eratura = -temps.eratura;
            temps.decimali = -temps.decimali;
            lcd_send_dat('-'); 
    }
```

Seems a bit for straight forward - allowing the compiler to handle the 2s compliment for you.

next:

```
temp = (temps.eratura/100)& 0x0F;
```

has very little space to work as the value can only go up to 128.  This is basically setting temp to 0 if temps.eratura is less than 100 and 1 if greater.  No need for the `&` here.  Ah, you are sending digits.  Ok.

```
temp = temps.eratura;

if(temp >= 100)
{
    temp -= 100;  
    lcd_send_dat('1');
}

if(temps.eratura >= 10)
{
    lcd_send_dat('0' + (temp / 10));
}

lcd_send_dat('0' + (temp % 10));
```

Then for your decimal:

```
const char decims[16] =
   {'0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '5', '6', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9'};
```

and

```
lcd_send_dat('.');  
lcd_send_dat(decims[temps.decimali]); 
lcd_send_dat(0xDF);
```

or we can get rid of the decims converter completely with:

```
lcd_send_dat('0' + ((temps.decimali * 10) / 16));
```

Basically, all these changes are allowing the compiler to do a little work for you and making the code easier to follow.

Comment: I tried a "struct" before using "union" but i got the same problem. The code there should do a 2's complement of both members of temps (a 1's complement plus one), both 8 bits long. 
Before adding the decimals (that's why i need to pass 2 values outside read_temp(); one for the whole temperature and one for the digits after the dot) it worked well, the values it gets from the sensor are evaluated correctly, then i added the "struct" and everything went wrong...

Comment: A `union` means that both members occupy the same memory location. I'm sure that's not what you want. Since changing it from a `struct` to a `union` didn't help anyway, I suggest changing it back to a `struct` and proceeding from there.

Comment: In the same way, those two lines don't make sense with your union, you are assigning it and immediately replacing the content on the next line:  
  
    temps.decimali = scratchpad[0] & 0x0F;
    temps.eratura = (scratchpad[1] << 4)|(scratchpad[0] >> 4);

Comment: thanks for the insight keith, i thought a 'union' meant a different thing (the two members were placed in sequential addresses in the same memory block, the same page in the pic memory structure), I change the code as you suggest.
Sorry etienne but i don't understand what you mean, I give 'temps.decimali' and 'temps.eratura' two different values. Of course that's what i THOUGHT I did before knowing how a 'union' works!

Comment: Thanks michael! I'm still thinking a lot in assembler so i have a hard time allowing the compiler to do work for me (as strange as this may sound!) now i feel i bit stupid about the 2's complement thing, it was so obvious since i'm dealing with signed numbers!

Comment: I come from an assembler background as well so I understand exactly where you are coming from.  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Your code improovements work like a charm when dealing with positive numbers (they also asks for less resources!) but as soon as i set a negative temperature the program starts behaving like before...i asked the same question on the microchip forum, hoping they know what's the problem. 
I now suspect it's something with the compiler because the PC jumps back and forth when the program performs certain operations so i think the compiler translates my code into strange instructions or calls for some functions that don't return well

Comment: Can you post the output of your device - what the program receives in the first 2 bytes of your "scratchPad" buffer?  Perhaps it is not returning a true negative number, but maybe something else.  If I could see an example of say -1.0, -1.5, -2.75, and say -100, I could see if that is the problem.  My guess is there may be an issue with negating the decimal portion of your input.  And just to confirm, PC means Program Counter here right?

Comment: NM, just seen your post.  Seems I had guessed correctly though :)

Answer (score -1):

It could be the C compiler optimizing the code, it can give the appearance of non-linear code execution. Try single stepping with the optimizer turned off.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.